# Pandas: Change index of series while chaining

Tags: pandas, indexing, series

Suppose I have a Pandas series

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
0 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 3
```

I can change the index by

```
>>> s.index = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a | 1
b | 2
c | 3
```

but how do I do this while chaining, like

```
s.apply(some_fun).<reindex to letters>.combine(...).etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html):

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s = s.set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c'])

print (s)
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `rename`:

```
new_idx = ['a','b','c']
s.rename(dict(zip(s.index, new_idx)))
```

Out:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```